# What should I do when Airflow task gets queued but never start running?

Tags: python, airflow

This is a simple question.

My Airflow sometimes gets queued but never starts running.
Does it mean I have an error in my code?
What should I do?

My environment:

- Python 3.7
- apache-airflow==2.2.2
- [aws-mwaa-local-runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner)

Comment: Perhaps check that the pool assigned to the DAG exists and it has empty slots.

Comment: @PApostol thank you for your reply! so, what you are suggesting is, I should look into see if the computing resource is available as expected or not. Good point. 
My pool seems to be available in this specific case.

Comment: hmm I'd suggest to raise an issue in the [Airflow repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/new/choose) with more details about your setup & DAG.

Comment: @PApostol Thank you so much for your responses. I think I shall take an appropriate step!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discussion, we should at least do the following.

- check that the pool assigned to the DAG exists and it has empty slots
- raise an issue in the [Airflow repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/new/choose) with more details about your setup & DAG